# npm run build fails with error originated from the build code

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-build

I'm building my app by running `npm run build` and it errors out
with this output:

```
/home/markalexa/blog/client/node_modules/react-dev-utils/node_modules/globby/index.js:47
            ...taskOptions,
            ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

it points to this code block in `index.js` within the `node_modules` directory:

```
const generateGlobTasks = (patterns, taskOptions) => {
    patterns = arrayUnion([].concat(patterns));
    assertPatternsInput(patterns);
    checkCwdOption(taskOptions);

    const globTasks = [];

    taskOptions = {
        ...taskOptions,    // <--
        ignore: [],
        expandDirectories: true

    };
```

The build has problem with the spread operator for some reason. Can you give me
any pointers to how to fix this ? I'm not really a npm developer.

node version:  6.11.4
npm version: 6.14.11

Thank you.

**Edit:**

After updating node to 8.6 which bumped up version of V8 as well
I'm getting this after running `npm run build`:

```
/home/markalexa/blog/client/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/make-dir.js:85
      } catch {
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Comment: Update your version of node.js to a newer version (`>=8.6.0`) because version `6.11.4` [does not support object spread properties](https://node.green/#ES2018-features-object-rest-spread-properties).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Node to 10.19 solved the problem. Looks like if you're not using
one of the most recent releases javascript code will break.

Answer (score 0):

I was using node v6 for working on another project. Using nvm, I switched to node v14 and the issue was resolved.